# git clone works locally but not from gitlab runner

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a weird behavior since this morning on my gitlab CI/CD. The git clone fails on the authentication step.
The error is as follow

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.iselection.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.xxx.com/xxx/'
```

Here is the yaml file

```
variables:
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "true""
  TOKEN_NAME: certificate
  TOKEN_VALUE: "xxx"
image: alpine:latest

before_script:
    - apk add git curl openssl openjdk11 bash ca-certificates
    - git clone https://$TOKEN_NAME:$TOKEN_VALUE@gitlab.xxx.com/xxx
```

So I am using a token defined in the repo I want to clone and when running the same command from my local machine, it works smoothly.

What can I check next or what can I do ?

Thx

edit: other failing tests

- creation of a PAT on my user (clone works from my machine but **not** from the Gitlab CICD pipeline)
- creation of a deploy token (clone works from my machine but **not** from the Gitlab CICD pipeline)

Comment: Have you checked whether someone revoked the token? Recreating a new token and replacing the old one with that might help.

Comment: Yes I did what you mentionned. The token was not revoked but I have created a new one just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with curl on the latest version of alpine right now. Try using Alpine version 3.11.13

```
image: alpine:3.11.13
```

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this same issue and it appears to be related to the latest cURL version (8.2.0). We pinned our `libcurl` and `curl` versions to 8.0.1 and it fixed the issue we had.

In our Alpine docker container, we updated to use:

```
apk add --update --upgrade --no-cache libcurl=8.0.1-r0 curl=8.0.1-r0 --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main
```

Comment: Thx. I’ll try on Monday and will give u feedback.